# Change type nvarchar to varchar for single table in EF6 - Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am attempting to change the default column type of a string field to varchar for a specific table (Contacts table) in my DB, using codefirst migrations with EF6.

I first attempted to implement this in my context class using:

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("varchar"));
```

This attempts to remap the entire db's string fields to varchar and produces a lengthy migration. I have used this migration as a template to produce a migration updating only the columns of my Contacts table. I now have a migration which is:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "FirstName", c => c.String(maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "LastName", c => c.String(maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "Company", c => c.String(maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "Position", c => c.String(maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "Notes", c => c.String(maxLength: 8000, unicode: false));
    }

public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "Notes", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "Position", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "Company", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "LastName", c => c.String());
        AlterColumn("dbo.Contacts", "FirstName", c => c.String());
    }
```

This is precisely what I want to occur, however when trying to update my database I see the following error:

```
Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. 
Please create a clustered index and try again.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I'm not sure what this error means, but I wondered if there was a standard way of getting past this error to apply the migration I have created.

Or alternatively is there a different way to accomplish my goal of setting the string default to varchar for my Contacts table, ensuring no impact on my current interactions with the table in code and no data loss.

Worth adding the my SQL db is hosted in Azure.

Comment: Do you **really** need 8000 characters for your first and last names? Really?? Not even Welsh or Icelandic names are **that long**.....

Comment: Any table in SQL Azure **must have** a clustered index. SQL Server will by default create a clustered index on your primary key - so what is the primary key on your table in question here?? Also: does this run other migrations at the same time? This one shown here doesn't drop any constraints - but that's what the error message seems to indicate - is there *more happening* than you're showing us here??

Comment: @marc_s My apologies, it seems the error is arising from an attempted migration `Applying automatic migration: 201512031244548_AutomaticMigration.`. This migration does not appear in my mirgrations folder, I don't know where it comes from/why it is attempting to apply it. Have you encountered this before?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't done much with migrations yet (still don't trust their SQL generation - prefer to write the SQL myself)

Comment: @JonnyKnottsvill I'd recommend you to stop using automatic migrations, and start using manual creations. Perhaps someone deleted the automatic migration from the project. Besides, I don't know if it's possible to write your own migration code in automatic migrations.